# parse object in json python

Tags: python, json

I have `json` file
Here is a snippet from the file

```
"objects": [
    {
      "address": {
        "fullAddress": "1"
      },
      "guid": "1",
      "name": "«1»",
      "region": {
        "name": "1",
        "code": "1"
      },
      "xsdData": {
        "shortName": "«2»",
        "City": "2",
        "Email": "2",
        "numberFederalList": "2",
        "Phone": "2",
        "SiteUrl": "2",
        "View": "2",
        "Fax": "",
        "ClassificationInformation": {
          "categoryStars": "три звезды",
          "InfoAccredOrganization": {
            "accredOrganization": "2",
            "accredOrganizationNumber": "2",
            "accredOrganizationShortName": "2",
            "specialist1": "2"
          },
          "order": {
            "dateEnd": "2",
            "licenseDateIssued": "2",
            "licenseNumber": "2"
          }
        },
        "InformationRooms": [
          {
            "InformationRoomsBlock": {
              "numberRooms": "182",
              "numberSeats": "304",
              "roomCategory": "Первая"
            }
          },
          {
            "InformationRoomsBlock": {
              "numberRooms": "1",
              "numberSeats": "4",
              "roomCategory": "Высшая \"апартамент\""
            }
          },
          {
            "InformationRoomsBlock": {
              "numberRooms": "1",
              "numberSeats": "2",
              "roomCategory": "Высшая \"сюит\""
            }
          },
          {
            "InformationRoomsBlock": {
              "numberRooms": "15",
              "numberSeats": "30",
              "roomCategory": "Высшая \"люкс\""
            }
          },
          {
            "InformationRoomsBlock": {
              "numberRooms": "3",
              "numberSeats": "6",
              "roomCategory": "Высшая \"джуниор сюит\""
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
```

I need to get variables `numberRooms` and `numberSeats`. And i need to write them into different variables.

Here is what i wrote

```
for record in json_data:   
 for add in record.get('objects', {}):
              for i in add['xsdData'].get('InformationRooms', {}):
                roomCategory = ['InformationRoomsBlock'][i]['roomCategory']
                if roomCategory == "Высшая \"сюит\"":
                    numberRooms_suit = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberRooms', '')
                    numberSeats_suit = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberSeats', '')
                elif roomCategory == "Первая":
                    numberRooms_first = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberRooms', '')
                    numberSeats_first = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberSeats', '')
                    print(numberSeats_first)
                elif roomCategory == "Первая для МГН":
                    numberRooms_mgn = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberRooms', '')
                    numberSeats_mgn = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberSeats', '')
                    print(numberSeats_mgn)
```

Еhis code works for 1-2 records, but there are many more. If run on a large `json` file, it gives the following error

```
roomCategory = ['InformationRoomsBlock'][i]['roomCategory']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Please tell me how to fix this or maybe I'm completely wrong in using the loop. I do not quite understand how to wade through such a file structure

Comment: `roomCategory = i['InformationRoomsBlock']['roomCategory']`

Could be better.

Comment: @JulienSorin I tried this option, but in this case it gives an error roomCategory = i['InformationRoomsBlock']['roomCategory']
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0):

```py
json_data = [{"objects": [{"address": {"fullAddress": "1"}, "guid": "1", "name": "«1»", "region": {"name": "1", "code": "1"}, "xsdData": {"shortName": "«2»", "City": "2", "Email": "2", "numberFederalList": "2", "Phone": "2", "SiteUrl": "2", "View": "2", "Fax": "", "ClassificationInformation": {"categoryStars": "тризвезды", "InfoAccredOrganization": {"accredOrganization": "2", "accredOrganizationNumber": "2", "accredOrganizationShortName": "2", "specialist1": "2"}, "order": {"dateEnd": "2", "licenseDateIssued": "2", "licenseNumber": "2"}}, "InformationRooms": [{"InformationRoomsBlock": {"numberRooms": "182", "numberSeats": "304", "roomCategory": "Первая"}}, {"InformationRoomsBlock": {"numberRooms": "1", "numberSeats": "4", "roomCategory": "Высшая\"апартамент\""}}, {"InformationRoomsBlock": {"numberRooms": "1", "numberSeats": "2", "roomCategory": "Высшая\"сюит\""}}, {"InformationRoomsBlock": {"numberRooms": "15", "numberSeats": "30", "roomCategory": "Высшая\"люкс\""}}, {"InformationRoomsBlock": {"numberRooms": "3", "numberSeats": "6", "roomCategory": "Высшая\"джуниорсюит\""}}]}}]}]


for record in json_data:
    for add in record.get('objects', {}):
        for i in add['xsdData'].get('InformationRooms', {}):
            roomCategory = i['InformationRoomsBlock']['roomCategory']
            if roomCategory == "Высшая \"сюит\"":
                numberRooms_suit = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberRooms', '')
                numberSeats_suit = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberSeats', '')
            elif roomCategory == "Первая":
                numberRooms_first = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberRooms', '')
                numberSeats_first = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberSeats', '')
                print(numberSeats_first)
            elif roomCategory == "Первая для МГН":
                numberRooms_mgn = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberRooms', '')
                numberSeats_mgn = i.get('InformationRoomsBlock', {}).get('numberSeats', '')
                print(numberSeats_mgn)
```

It works for me...
It prints **304**.